# word wrap text in div

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to get the product name for each item to fit into the div I've tried using word-wrap: break-word; // word-wrap: break-all; but both didn't work. I also tried setting the width of each div instead of % but didn't work text flows over the next items text.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.scrolls {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: solid transparent;
  width: 60vw;
}

.scrolls .product {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid transparent;
  width: 30%;
  height: 240px;
}

.scrolls .product .details {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.scrolls .product .details ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.scrolls .product .details .liProductName {
  max-width: 150px;
  word-break: break-all;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolls">
  <div class="product" ng-repeat="i in products track by $index" align="center">
    <div class="details">
      <ul>
        <li class="liProductName"> Portable 20000mAh USB Power Bank LED LCD For Cell Phone External Battery</li>
        <li><img style="width: 90px; height: 120px;" data-ng-src="{{img}}" /></li>
        <li><button id="addItemBtn" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addItem(i.productId)">Add</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your website link.

Comment: @Shital: no, the OP needs to post sufficient code to reproduce the problem in the question. Otherwise, as soon as the problem is fixed there will be no opportunity for future visitors to learn, as the problem will no longer be present. We actively request those asking questions *not* to post a link to their website; please see: "[Something in my web site...doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well maybe you want to try something like this?

```
.scrolls .product .details .liProductName {
    max-width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Otherwise maybe you want something like this:

```
.scrolls .product .details .liProductName {
    max-width: 150px;
    word-break: break-word;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This would do the job, also did do the changes in the codesnippet below.

```css
.scrolls {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: solid transparent;
  width: 60vw;
}

.scrolls .product {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid transparent;
  width: 30%;
  height: 240px;
}

.scrolls .product .details {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.scrolls .product .details ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.scrolls .product .details .liProductName1 {
  max-width: 150px;
  word-break: break-word;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.scrolls .product .details .liProductName2 {
  max-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolls">
  <div class="product" ng-repeat="i in products track by $index" align="center">
    <div class="details">
      <ul>
        <li class="liProductName1"> Portable 20000mAh USB Power Bank LED LCD For Cell Phone External Battery</li>
        <li><img style="width: 90px; height: 120px;" data-ng-src="{{img}}" /></li>
        <li><button id="addItemBtn" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addItem(i.productId)">Add</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="scrolls">
  <div class="product" ng-repeat="i in products track by $index" align="center">
    <div class="details">
      <ul>
        <li class="liProductName2"> Portable 20000mAh USB Power Bank LED LCD For Cell Phone External Battery</li>
        <li><img style="width: 90px; height: 120px;" data-ng-src="{{img}}" /></li>
        <li><button id="addItemBtn" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addItem(i.productId)">Add</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, good to hear I helped you, could you please vote my answer and give the status as answer of the question? Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 0):

try this below code with !important "word-wrap:break-word !important;"

```
.scrolls .product .details .liProductName{
        max-width:150px;
        border:1px solid red;
        word-wrap:break-word !important;
    }
```